# Find an ordered basis $B$ of $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am a bit confused on this question.

Given $T$ is a linear map $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ whose matrix form is
$$
  A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

This satisfies $T^2 = T$. Prove that if $S$ is a linear transformation on $\mathbb R^2$ such that $S^2 = S$, then $S = 0$ or $S$ is the identity, or there is an ordered basis $B$ of $\mathbb R^2$ that $[S]_B = A$ above.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you covered the rank-nullity theorem? If so, I suggest breaking into 3 cases depending on the rank of $S$.

Comment: Can you please a bit more details on what 3 cases here? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First show that if $v$ is in the image (AKA column space) of $S$, then $Sv=v$.

The rank of $S$ is an integer between $0$ and $2$.

If $\mathrm{rk}\,S=0$, show that $S=0$.

If $\mathrm{rk}\,S=1$ then the nullity of $S$ is also $1$. Let $b_1$ span the image of $S$ and let $b_2$ span the nullspace (AKA kernel) of $S$. Show that $b_1,b_2$ are linearly independent, and that $[S]_{\{b_1,b_2\}}=A$.

If $\mathrm{rk}\,S=2$, then the image of $S$ is $\mathbb R^2$; show that $S$ is the identity.